# DocumentDb GUID Index Precision

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Let's say we have a non-unique GUID/UUID value in our documents:

```
[
  {
    "id": "123456",
    "Key": "117dfd49-a71d-413b-a9b1-841e88db06e8"
    "Name": "Kaapstad",
  },
  ...
]
```

We want to query upon this through equality only. No range or orderby querying required. E.g:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.Key = "117dfd49-a71d-413b-a9b1-841e88db06e8"
```

Below is the index definition. It's a hash index (since no range querying will be performed) using a `String` data type (since Javascript doesn't support Guid natively)

```
collection.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(
    new IncludedPath { 
        Path = "/Key/?", 
        Indexes = new Collection<Index> { 
            new HashIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 }
        }
    });
```

**But what is the best indexing precision for this?**

[This MSDN page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-indexing-policies/) doesn't make it clear to me as to what precision value would be most suited to such a value:

> Index precision configuration is more useful with string ranges. Since
>   strings can be any arbitrary length, the choice of the index precision
>   can impact the performance of string range queries, and impact the
>   amount of index storage space required. String range indexes can be
>   configured with 1-100 or -1 ("maximum"). If you would like to perform
>   Order By queries against string properties, then you must specify a
>   precision of -1 for the corresponding paths.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can fine-tune the indexing precision value depending on the number of documents you expect to contain the path for your property key (which happens to be the `Key` property in your example).

The indexing precision for a hash index indicates the number of bytes to hash the property value to. Thus, lowering the precision value helps optimize the amount of storage required to store the index. Raising the precision value (in the context of a hash index) helps guard against hash collisions on the index.

For example, let's assume a hash index precision value of 3 on the path `foo`.

3 bytes = 3 * 8 = 24 bits.

24 bits can support: 2^24 = 16,777,216 values

By pigeonhole principle, you are guaranteed to have a hash collision when storing >16,777,216 documents with a `foo` property. Upon a hash collision, DocumentDB will then need to perform a scan on the subset of documents found. For example, if you had 30,000,000 documents with a `foo` property - you can expect to scan across 2 documents on average.

Comment: Excellent answer. I can't find anything like this in the documentation, but perhaps I didn't look hard enough!